# restTemplate returns "Count not extract response" exception

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have following code to consume a REST webservice and convert the results;however, when I run the code it returns following exception, I am also not sure how to handle other type of responses for example if a response with error code in its body is returned. I have found this questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815182/org-springframework-web-client-restclientexception-could-not-extract-response) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387716/resttemplate-restclientexception-could-not-extract-response) with similar topics but did not find much there.

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class com.project.web.FlightsResults] and content type [application/xml]
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:576)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:537)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:244)
    at com.project.web.ArticleController.showArticles(ArticleController.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
....
```

The rest template code is as following:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Map<String, String> vars = new HashMap<String, String>();
        vars.put("user", "username");
        vars.put("key", "password");
        vars.put("fl", "po");
        AvailabilityResponse flightResults = restTemplate
                .getForObject(
                        "http://example.com/availabilityRequest?user={user}&key={key}&fl_type={fl}",
                        AvailabilityResponse.class, vars);
        System.err.println(">>"
                + flightResults.getFlightList().get(0).getFlightOptions()
                        .getFlightOption().size());
```

**XMLElements**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "availabilityResponse")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class AvailabilityResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "flightList")
    private List<FlightList> flightList;

    public AvailabilityResponse() {
        this.flightList = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List<FlightList> getFlightList() {
        return flightList;
    }

    public void setFlightList(List<FlightList> flightList) {
        this.flightList = flightList;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "flightList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FlightList {

    @XmlElement(name = "flightOptions")
    private FlightOptions flightOptions;

    public FlightOptions getFlightOptions() {
        return flightOptions;
    }

    public void setFlightOptions(FlightOptions flightOptions) {
        this.flightOptions = flightOptions;
    }

}


@XmlRootElement(name = "flightOptions")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FlightOptions {

    @XmlElement(name = "flightOption")
    private List<FlightOption> flightOption;

    public FlightOptions() {
        this.flightOption = new ArrayList();
    }

    public List<FlightOption> getFlightOption() {
        return flightOption;
    }

    public void setFlightOption(List<FlightOption> flightOption) {
        this.flightOption = flightOption;
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name = "flightOption")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FlightOption {

    @XmlElement(name = "viaIata")
    private String viaIata;
    @XmlElement(name = "fromDate")
    private String fromDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "toDate")
    private String toDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "fromTime")
    private String fromTime;
    @XmlElement(name = "toTime")
    private String toTime;
    @XmlElement(name = "flightNum")
    private String flightNum;
    @XmlElement(name = "class")
    private String fclass;
    @XmlElement(name = "flightlegs")
    private List<FlightLeg> flightLegs;
    @XmlElement(name = "prices")
    private Prices prices;

    public FlightOption() {
        this.flightLegs = new ArrayList();
        this.prices = new Prices();
    }
             getters and setters


@XmlRootElement (name = "prices")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Prices {
    @XmlElement (name ="adult")
    private float adult;
    @XmlElement (name ="child")
    private float child;
    @XmlElement (name = "infant")
    private float infant;
    @XmlElement (name = "total")
    private Total total;
              getters and setters

@XmlRootElement (name = "total")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Total {
      @XmlAttribute (name ="serviceCharge")
    private float serviceCharge;
    @XmlAttribute (name = "taxCharge")
    private float taxCharge;
    @XmlAttribute (name ="taxGeneral")
    private float taxGeneral;
    @XmlAttribute (name = "totalPrice")
    private float totalPrice;
    @XmlAttribute (name ="currency")
    private String currency;

     getters and setters
```

**REST response**

```
  <availabilityResponse version="3">
    <flightList fromIata="FRA" toIata="YYZ" flightsFound="8">
        <flightOptions>
            <flightOption>
                <viaIata>FRA-YHZ-YYZ</viaIata>
                <fromDate>2015-06-06</fromDate>
                <fromTime>13:15:00</fromTime>
                <toDate>2015-06-06</toDate>
                <toTime>20:10:00</toTime>
                <flightNum>DEA062</flightNum>
                <class>C</class>
                <flightlegs>
                    <flightlegdetail fromIata="FRA" toIata="YHZ">
                        <fromDate>2015-06-06</fromDate>
                        <fromTime>13:15:00</fromTime>
                        <toDate>2015-06-06</toDate>
                        <toTime>15:35:00</toTime>
                        <flightNum>DE6062</flightNum>
                    </flightlegdetail>
                </flightlegs>
                <flightlegs>
                    <flightlegdetail fromIata="YHZ" toIata="YYZ">
                        <fromDate>2015-06-06</fromDate>
                        <fromTime>18:50:00</fromTime>
                        <toDate>2015-06-06</toDate>
                        <toTime>20:10:00</toTime>
                        <flightNum>WS269</flightNum>
                    </flightlegdetail>
                </flightlegs>
                <prices currency="EUR" specialOffer="true">
                    <adult>724.22</adult>
                    <child>725.00</child>
                    <infant>73.00</infant>
                    <total serviceCharge="0.00" taxCharge="85.77" taxGeneral="85.77"
                        flightPrice="724.22" totalPrice="809.99" currency="EUR" />
                </prices>
            </flightOption>
            <flightOption>
                <viaIata>FRA-YYZ</viaIata>
                 .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is because you have not registered message convertors for handling xml responses returned from the service. You can use xstream marshallers etc and there are plenty of example out there in web.

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=546

https://spring.io/blog/2009/03/27/rest-in-spring-3-resttemplate